# Unexpected token '.' when adding function to prototype

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create the javascript equivalent of a purely virtual base class. But I get a syntax error, "Unexpected token .". What's wrong with the syntax?

```
MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.Repository = {
    Repository.prototype.Get = function(id) { // <-- error occurs here

    }

    Repository.prototype.GetAll = function() {

    }

    Repository.prototype.Add = function(entity) {

    }

    Repository.prototype.AddRange = function(entities) {

    }

    Repository.prototype.Remove = function(entity) {

    }

    Repository.prototype.RemoveRange = function(entities) {

    }
}
```

Edit: Here's how the namespaces are constructed.

```
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};

MyNamespace.createNamespace = function (namespace) {
    var nsparts = namespace.split(".");
    var parent = MyNamespace;

    if (nsparts[0] === "MyNamespace") {
        nsparts = nsparts.slice(1);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < nsparts.length; i++) {
        var partname = nsparts[i];

        if (typeof parent[partname] === "undefined") {
            parent[partname] = {};
        }

        parent = parent[partname];
    }

    return parent;
};

MyNamespace.createNamespace("MyNamespace.MySubNamespace");
```

Comment: Good read on Javascript subclassing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

Comment: The code is invalid.... You have an object and you are setting code inside of it....

Answer (score 3):

Your code is expecting an object, but you are treating the object as a method.

```
MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.Repository = {   <-- Object start
    Repository.prototype.Get = function(id) { // <-- You are setting a method...
```

What you should be doing is

```
MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.Repository = function() { };
MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.Repository.prototype = {
    get : function(){},
    add : function(){}
};
```

Comment: Doing it this way replaces the original error with: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'prototype' of undefined"

Comment: I think you may want to expand your answer with how to construct the object inheritance as well, since the 'namespace' nested object doesn't appear to be a set of functions.

Comment: @Legion well you would need to set `Repository` first.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the namespace construction.

Answer (score 0):

`prototype` property is for functions ,`Repository` is an object it doesn't have  a `prototype` property.

Answer (score -1):

Uhm, you need to define each level of that namespace, and then you need to understand that what you're setting Repository to is not a block of code like a class, but an object literal, and thus must use the appropriate syntax.

```
var MyNamespace = {MySubNamespace: {}};

MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.Repository = { // This is not a block. This is an object literal.
    Get: function(id) {

    },

    GetAll: function() {

    },

    Add: function(entity) {

    },

    AddRange: function(entities) {

    },

    Remove: function(entity) {

    },

    RemoveRange: function(entities) {

    }
};
```

Comment: The namespaces are defined properly, I just excluded it from the post for clarity.

Comment: This isn't using prototypal inheritance though. The methods will be redefined for every instance.

Comment: I'm just correcting the code of what OP provided. I'm not commenting on how op should do something because it's not entirely clear what he's doing. He could be making an object to set as a prototype object to a function later.